# Generate AES-256-GCM key

Tags: openssl, aes, key-generation, aead

I'm using `aes-256-gcm` encryption. I used a sample key provided in the docs and it works fine.

I also tried a key generated from [here](https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/Security-Encryption-Key-Generator.aspx) and it works fine. There's no option to specify `gcm` here yet the key generated works fine.

I'm trying to generate the key using `openssl` using the command

`openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -k secret -P -md sha1`

inspired from [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/imdm/12.0?topic=encryption-generating-aes-keys-password) but I'm getting the error

`enc: AEAD ciphers not supported`

How can I generate the keys in `.pem` format using a command line utility?

An example of the key that works from the docs is as follows

`4u7x!A%D*G-KaPdRgUkXp2s5v8y/B?E(`

Comment: Here's why openssl does not support it: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12220

Comment: @Spyros how can I generate it then?

Comment: gcm is an encryption mode, I'm not sure I understand the question. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things to unpack here.

First, regardless of the AES mode being used (GCM, CBC, ECB, CTR, etc), if you are using AES-256, then the key must be 256 bits in length.  To generate a random 256-bit key, encoded in hexadecimal format, you can use the following command:

```
head /dev/urandom | sha256sum
```

This produces a random 256-bit key, such as:

```
3fd00454580de44ea216d8b7b234267a2a6a6aec7e56d2b38e641a45597af0f2
```

Now, you can use this key with an iv with openssl to encrypt some plain text using aes-256-cbc, like so:

```
echo -n 'hello world' |  openssl aes-256-cbc -e -K 3fd00454580de44ea216d8b7b234267a2a6a6aec7e56d2b38e641a45597af0f2 -iv 302775dfc35a35c8081bbc6fdeacbd86 | xxd -p
```

This produces the cyphertext:

```
7d5b44298bf959af149a0086d79334e6
```

Now, you can decrypt the ciphertext using the same key and iv, to produce the original plainext, like so:

```
echo -n '7d5b44298bf959af149a0086d79334e6' | xxd -p -r | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K 3fd00454580de44ea216d8b7b234267a2a6a6aec7e56d2b38e641a45597af0f2 -iv 302775dfc35a35c8081bbc6fdeacbd86
```

This produces:

```
hello world
```

However, you asked about using openssl to do AES encryption using GCM mode, not CBC mode.  Unfortunately, this is not possible with the command line interface for openssl, because AES-GCM is not supported.  For more info on this, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html, and scroll down to the section 'supported ciphers, and note where it reads:

> The enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like
> CCM and GCM, and will not support such modes in the future. The enc
> interface by necessity must begin streaming output (e.g., to standard
> output when -out is not used) before the authentication tag could be
> validated, leading to the usage of enc in pipelines that begin
> processing untrusted data and are not capable of rolling back upon
> authentication failure.

Comment: Instead of using a shasum to generate a fixed-sized key, we could pick the correct number of bytes from urandom and then encode them, or just use `openssl rand -hex 32` (length specified in bytes).

Answer (score 3):

We speak about *key generation* only then, when it is hard to do that manually. For instance, to create a pair of keys for RSA or for a specific ECC curve like 25519, one needs to do a lot of computations with relatively big numbers.

Keys for AES-256 can easily be created *manually*. *Any* 256 bit long bit sequence can be used as an AES-256 key. You *don't have* to use any generators and create a *valid* key *manually*. Human generated keys have usually less entropy than the generated by some quality random generator that is based on quality entropy source, that's why it is recommended to use a generator.

PEM format is used for PKI only. PKI uses *asymmetric* encryption. Where as AES is *symmetric* algorithm. In case of AES there is no private key, public key, certificates, that's why PEM is not applicable in case of AES.

Comment: So in what file format can I store the key?

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida: It depends on how are you going to use it. If your application reads the key in binary format from file, store it as binary in the file. If your application reads it as binary from the database, store it as a BLOB in the database. If the application expects the key as a text, e.g. in the hexadecimal or in the Base64 format, use this format.

Comment: I need it as a text. So is it fine if I store it as base64 in a `txt` file? Or a `.key` file.

Comment: To keep it as a text, you can use hexadecimal or Base64 format. Why do you ask about format?

Comment: My concern is not the format. It's the type of file I should the store the key in.

Comment: Why are you concerned about file type?

Comment: No particular reason. I'm a beginner doing it for the first time to trying to do the ideal thing.

Comment: For passwords for symmetric encryption there is standard, because actually there is no need in sch standard. In case of asymmetric encryption like RSA or ECC you need to send you public to other parties, or they need to download your public key or normally your certificate. Also you want to store public keys or certificates of other parties locally. To enable interoperability, some standards are needed. That's there is PEM and other formats.

Comment: But in case of symmetric encryption you don't share your passwords with anyone. That's why there is not much need in any standards for that. One more difference: You can store certificates e.g. in PEM format in some directory and make then readable to all application in the system. Whereas you normally don't want that any application can read your passwords for symmetric encryption. That's why passwords for symmetric encryption are often stored in some **password manager**.